# C# InvokeMember("click")

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to make an WinForm app and i need to use the InvokeMember utility of the GetElementByTag("anytagname").GetElementByName("anyname")[x] and it's work! but, when does click dont stop, and does click in infinit loop.

Comment: I try to put in a for loop and i get the same result

Comment: Hi Caiqui, can you please improve this question with some code? Other members will need to reproduce your error in order to help fix it, so if you could walk through the process that would be useful.

Comment: Si claro con gusto en un momento paso el fragmento de código que me da error

Comment: You should edit your comment and take out your password. You should probably reset the password, also.

Comment: ooo gracias, ya dejé todo en orden